# What is the best way to increment answers count for post like in SO?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building forum like StackOwerflow. My tehcnology stack are NodeJS/MongoDB/Mongoose. My problem is I don't understand how to make atomic updates of questions posts when new answers added.

Look at my posts collection:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  title: 'How to learn JavaScript'
  body: 'Subject',
  answers_count: 2
},
{
  id: 2,
  parentId: 1,
  body: 'Read book'
},
{
  id: 3,
  parentId: 1,
  body: 'Watch YouTube'
}]
```

When I add or remove new answers I need to increment `answers_count` in parant post. What is the best way to make atomic updates?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into the MongoDB documentation on atomicity and two-phase commits? That might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Say your question model is named `Question` and answer model `Answer`. Then you can make the update like this:

```
Answer.create({
    //the answer object you have
},
function(err,res){
    if(err) 
        console.log(err);
    else {
        Question.findOneAndUpdate({
            id: //answer's parent id
        }, 
        {
            $inc:{ answer_count:1 }
        },
        function(err,res){
            if(err) 
                console.log(err);
            else 
                console.log("Answer count incremented. The updated question is "+res);
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But your solution is not atomic

Comment: @Erik what do you mean by atomic?

Comment: if your second query `Question.findOneAndUpdate` then first one `Answer.create` should be rollback